# PFQueryTableViewController working with Cloud function

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

There is cloud function which I have created.

Now, if I use PFQueryTableViewController then it has method call queryForTable, through which we can load the table. Problem arises when we try to use cloud function.

How will I use cloud function which will work with PFQueryTableViewController and provide inbuilt features of it like Refreshing the table and loadMore feature.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
.....

return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a `PFQueryTableViewController`, it's dependent on obtaining the results from a `PFQuery`. You can use a regular `UITableViewController` if your data source is not a `PFQuery`.

Comment: I have created a similar class like PFQueryTableViewController for Cloud function calls. Let me know if you have any feedback for it or want to update it. https://github.com/nikso/CloudController.git